# How was the first year? What will the second bring?

Tags: discussion, community

The private beta started March 13th, 2014. It is our site's First Anniversary.

Thanks to everybody for participating!

This seems like a  good occasion to share memories, ideas, hopes, plans etc.
Please, add answers or comments if you like.

Answer (score 7):

joined MESE back in september or october, i believe.  Since then, I have basically always had it on in a tab in the background and will periodically check it throughout the day.  The quality of both questions and answers is so astounding, I find myself learning new things not only about math education but also mathematics and a litany of other topics that pop up in the little sidebar with other SE sites.  I must say a sincere thank you to everyone who has participated in MESE, it truly has and will continue to be the choicest of educational experiences.

I have been especially impressed at the caliber of questions and answers that have been happening in the past month.  If this is any sign as to what the future brings, someone start to get the icon art ready! i vote for a blackboard with the word MATH (like the LOVE park sign or something) or some mathematical symbols ;)

Comment: this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_(sculpture)

Comment: exactly what i was talking about :)

Comment: "the caliber of questions and answers": Anyone have a conjecture on the increased traffic and quality recently? Possibly this MO/Meta question? "[How should we react to the existence of Math Educators SE?](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2155/6094)."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, let us hope we make it to graduation at some point. It is always nice to see the new designs emerge.

Answer (score 7):

I participated frequently in the beginning of matheducators SE, but became less active last summer. I decided to participate again because of the recent growth of matheducators.se. A Math Ed student in a university I was interviewing at brought up MESE, and it amazed me to see how far this site had spread.

I see one of the greatest strengths of this site is it's capacity to ask "Why?" type questions instead of the "How?" type questions of MSE and MO. This is the only place where people can regularly ask about the motivation of mathematical concepts, their place in the curriculum, the best way to understand and teach them. It is a great benefit to all mathematicians and math students, not just to math educators.

It's other greatest strength is the great answerers. Even though I haven't been active on this site, I've read through the popular questions, and I think you guys have done a fantastic job. I especially appreciate how everyone has a kinder tone on this site (compared to MSE and MO) while still closing off-topic questions. It's a great example to other sites.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was glad to see you back. Your activities of driving traffic to the site were/are really helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I've been hanging around since the around the beginning. I find this forum wonderful in discussing new ideas and bouncing around ways to improve our teaching. So many different people bringing in their own research, abilities, and vast knowledge has really helped so many more. I am also impressed with the questions as of late, I hope the trend continues.

I hope that in the future, we can attract more members and improve the quantity of our questions. We seem to have a strong main user base, which is great, but many users are popping in to just ask a question and leave again.

Just a few things that can use improving:

- Not many people are selecting answers to questions. Some could use a community wiki format as well.
- Some of the titles to questions are a little too general for searching through Google. Perhaps a more conscious effort to adjust titles is needed.
- More use of the meta to discuss some addition refinement of the stack.

Comment: Thank you for raising those points. Very good point regarding the titles! We could start a small campaign on this.  I did not pay attention to the accept-rate. I will try to compare to some other sites. It could be that it is as we have relatively many answers and sometimes things are not as clear cut so users hesitate. I am not sure I understand what you mean with the wiki-format.   Yes, meta got a bit deserted over time. Do not hesitate to stat some discussion, such as for example on the titles.

Comment: @quid I meant it as away to address those questions that don't have a clear cut answer, allowing us to pool all the good ones together.

Comment: Now I understand. I agree, this would indeed be good for some questions.